# XMLHttpRequest open() function is not working even I use a copy of the same code in another part of my system

Tags: javascript, php, php-7

I´m going to try to explain what my problem is.

I have this code

```
const deleted = document.querySelector('form#delete');
const edited  = document.querySelector('form#edit');

eventListeners();

function eventListeners() {
    deleted.addEventListener('submit', markDeleted);
    edited.addEventListener('submit', userEdit);
}

function markDeleted(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log('^*^*^ delete *^*^*');

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('POST', '/models/comm.model.php', true);

    console.log('^*^*^ after xhr.open *^*^*');

    // SOME MORE CODE ...
```

My problem is where I open the communication

```
xhr.open('POST', '/models/comm.model.php', true);
```

because never executes comm.model.php file even I use the same file
to login and register new users

this is my comm.model.php file

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/config/constants.php';

print_r("inside comm model");

$accion = filter_var($_POST['tipoAccion'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if ($accion === 'login') {
  // some code ...
}

if ($accion === 'register') {
  // some code ...
}

if ($accion === 'userDelete') {
    print_r($accion);
}
```

Here is the browser console image

[image: this is the image when I click on userDelete]

[image: when i click on register]

So you can see there is no problem with comm.model.php file

thank you for any help

---

@epascarello

here is the complete code you asked for

```
function markDeleted(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log('^*^*^ delete *^*^*');

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/models/comm.model.php', true);

    console.log('^*^*^ after xhr.open *^*^*');

    xhr.onload = function () {

        console.log('^*^*^ inside onload *^*^*');

        if (this.status === 200) {

            console.log('^*^*^ responseText no parse *^*^*');
            console.log(xhr.responseText);

            respuesta = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            switch (respuesta[0]) {
                case 'nok':
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: 'Error',
                        text: 'El usuario NO pudo ser eliminado',
                        icon: 'error',
                        showClass: {
                            popup: 'animate__animated animate__zoomIn'
                        },
                        hideClass: {
                            popup: 'animate__animated animate__zoomOut'
                        }
                    })
                    break;
                case 'ok':
                    if (respuesta[2] === 'userDelete') {
                        Swal.fire({
                            title: 'Usuario eliminado correctamente',
                            icon: 'success',
                            showClass: {
                                popup: 'animate__animated animate__zoomIn'
                            },
                            hideClass: {
                                popup: 'animate__animated animate__zoomOut'
                            }
                        }).then((resultado) => {
                            console.log(resultado.value);
                            if (resultado.value) {
                                window.location.href = '/master.php';
                            }
                        })
                    } else {
                        Swal.fire({
                            title: 'Error',
                            text: 'El usuario NO pudo ser eliminado',
                            icon: 'error',
                            showClass: {
                                popup: 'animate__animated animate__rotateIn'
                            },
                            hideClass: {
                                popup: 'animate__animated animate__rotateOut'
                            },
                            showConfirmButton: false,
                            timer: 2500
                        })
                    }
                    break;    
                // default:
                //     break;
            }
            xhr.send(usuario);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the send? Open does not make the request.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @epascarello i didn't post all my code but it comes ahead

Comment: "but it comes ahead" no clue what that means. You need to post more code to show the useage of the XMLHttpRequest object

Comment: @epascarello I just edited the post and put all the code of that function

Comment: The send is inside the onload....